# Can Resharper have special settings for enum?

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

I'm using Resharper 5.1.1 to reformat my code (Cleanup Code, Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C). I can't get it to format my code the way I want it to. I want my code to look like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public enum Sex {Male, Female}

    public Sex Gender { get; set; }

    public Person(Sex gender)
    {
        Gender = gender;
    }
}
```

My problem is with the `enum`. Since an enum is a type, just as a class is a type, they are treated the same. Therefor, the enum is formatted as

```
public enum Sex
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

The curly braces of the type (i.e. the `enum`) are placed on a separate line and the members are also placed on a separate line. For a Class that is exactly what I want. But for a (simple) `enum` I just want them on a single line.

For an auto property there is an exception (Place abstract property/indexer/event declaration on single line), so  the auto property is formatted the way I want it to.

Is there an option in Resharper to have it place an enum on a single line?

**Update**
After posting the same question on the [Resharper forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5282669), I've been told it currently isn't possible. A [Feature Request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-203629) has been created for it. If you also feel this is an option you'd like to see in a future version of Resharper, please vote for the request.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to make nested Types private. If a type is public, it should live in a proper namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question but the answer has changed.

In Visual Studio 2019 with Resharper 2019.1.1 (and probably in older ones) you can configure line breaks of enums in:

Extensions > ReSharper > Options... > Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Line Breaks and Wrapping > Arrangement of Enumerations

Answer (score 3):

Taking a look at the options of ReSharper, I found no option, too.

Maybe if you post the question in the [ReSharper forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/resharper_community) you can get direct response from their developers or support engineers.

Comment: I repeated the question in the [ReSharper forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/293079).

Comment: It isn't possible, but a feature request has been created. See the update in my question.